# Area - Square of Perimeter Ratio

Tags: geometry, area

I am currently working at a GIS (Geographical Information Systems)-related project where we have a bunch of pieces of land. I want to study whether the shape of each piece influences a target variable.

For that matter, I calculated the ratio $Q:=\frac{4\pi A}{P^2}$ for each of the regions (where $A$ stands for its area and $P$ for its perimeter) The idea is that high values of $Q$ represent circle-like shapes (with a lot of area for a given perimeter) while low values represent "thin and stretched rectangles"

The $4\pi$ factor is there so that the values of $Q$ have a $(0,1)$ range, but there is no real need for that. I chose to divide by $P^2$ so that $Q$ is adimensional and does not depend on the size of the region (I already have other variable that take size into account) The real regions I'm working with come in a huge variety of shapes (as they come from Geographical data) The total amount of regions is close to $700$.

So the problem I have is the following: There is a pretty strong ($-0.34$ in a sample of about $700$) correlation between area and $Q$ Given how $Q$ is conceived, shouldn't it be close to $0$? Is $Q$ an actual good measure of how "circle-like" my area is? Are there any sound alternatives?

As @user pointed out in his comment, it is possible that there is an actual correlation between $Q$ and region size, with smaller regions being more "regular" (higher $Q$) Can you think of a possible explanation why that may be the case? The "regions" are connected chunks of forest. @quarague made a very good point regarding the map resolution, so I tried to check it that's the case.

[image: Plot]

I am not sure if this plot reflects that, since you can find a wide range of values of $Q$ for small regions, while the rarity seems to be "big regions with circle-like shapes". It could also be, though, that the map resolution erases "some" of the irregularities

Comment: I would consider a possibility that the data are really correlated (for example all large rectangles are almost squares).

Comment: I would also expect that the correlation you found is just there. This may be related to the resolution that you have for your shapes. The small areas all look almost square in your data because you don't have that detailed measurements. For bigger areas the same level of detail can result in much more complicated shapes.

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't give the sizes in terms of pixels. In a discrete world, the shapes have a finite number of possible isoperimetric values, which is small for small blobs. This introduces a bias.